# Api Test : Postman vs Python Requests

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests, postman

I could send post request using postman. But I it fails with python requests library:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers)
```

Why postman test is ok? What is the difference between postman and python request post?

Comment: You can get the exact code for the request Postman made. See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v5/sending_and_viewing_responses/code_snippets

Comment: Where’s the rest of it?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule you saved me from baldness!! Thanks

Comment: @TheNone You can answer your question if you have solved it . Would be nice to know the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - Just to answer the question as the original link by @OluwafemiSule now returns 404. In Postman, on the upper right hand side just below the "Send" pull down is a small text button labeled "Code".  Press that and you can chose to see the transmission coded to run in a large number of languages - including python/requests.  An updated link as of 02/2019: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/#___gatsby